# How do I configure Ruby On Rails on windows XP with APACHE and MYSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

It has been quite some time I am struggling to get Ruby On Rails working on my System which is having Windows XP operating system.

I am trying to configure ROR to use apache and mysql so that I do not have to install additional servers to run ruby on rails.

I also tried InstantRails but faced same problems.

I went through the tutorial mentioned in [getting rails to wrok on a windows machine running xampp](http://www.grapethinking.com/getting-rails-to-work-on-a-windows-machine-running-xampp) and did all the steps which were necessary.

All went fine (installing rails, running the ruby, gem and rails command from command prompt) but when I tried to run my application by typing localhost:3000/say/hello nothing happened and I was redirected to the google page for searching to this keyword.

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [BitNami RubyStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack), it is free and works on Windows

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended, Ruby has poor performances on Windows for now, and lots of gems will only works on POSIX systems.